# Is there any possible way to deploy Django app without "setup python app" feature in Cpanel?

Tags: django, cpanel

I was trying to deploy my Django app on a Hostgator Cpanel. But there is no "set up python app" feature present on my Cpanel. I have come to know that I have to buy the CloudLinux feature to get that. Is there any way to set the application root, startup file, and other things provided by that(including starting and stopping my app anytime) to run my Django app?

Comment: Hi! Have you tried pythonanywhere.i really like it it is my favorite.here is the link https://www.pythonanywhere.com/